# Redis: find items active on a given date

Tags: redis

I have a bunch of objects with start and end dates like so:

```
{id: "1", start_date: "2020-01-01", end_date: "2020-01-15"}
{id: "2", start_date: "2020-01-15", end_date: "2020-01-30"}
{id: "3", start_date: "2020-01-07", end_date: "2020-02-01"}
{id: "4", start_date: "2020-02-01", end_date: "2020-02-15"}
```

What I need to do is find the objects that are active on a given date. For example, given the date "2020-01-10", it should return objects 1 and 3 since their start_date is <= to 2020-01-10 and their end_date is >= 2020-01-10.

What is the proper Redis data structure to be able to perform this type of lookup? Sorted sets seem like the right choice, but I can't wrap my head around how to perform this sort of lookup with sorted sets.

Comment: I can do it in two passes:

```
zadd obj_start 0 20200101:1
1
zadd obj_end 0 20200115:1
1
zadd obj_start 0 20200115:2
1
zadd obj_end 0 20200130:2
1
zadd ob_start 0 20200107:3
1
zadd obj_end 0 20200201:3
1
zadd obj_start 0 20200201:4
1
zadd obj_end 0 20200215:4


zrangebylex obj_start - [20200110
20200101:1
20200107:3

zrangebylex obj_end [20200110 +
20200115:1
20200130:2
20200201:3
20200215:4
```

And then in code find the common object ids in both results in that's my set, but I'd like to be able to do it all in redis alone if possible.

Comment: Brian did you check [RediSearch](https://redisearch.io)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755663/creating-a-new-set-from-a-range-of-a-sorted-set-in-redis